# upgrade fail from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, ssd

upgrade fail from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS. the files stop unpacking during the installation. so right now, The grub menu works and I can put my login information but nothing load up after that. No files displayed on the desk and no access to the terminal.

so what can I do at this point to recover my files and reverse back to 20.04?

I plan to take out the SSD and get files and wipe everything on the SSD and reinstall the operating system

However, I also have a windows system load on the computer. Is there a way I can have access to my linux files from the windows side?

Besides taking out the SSD and transfer the files, any other suggestions I can try here?

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your description, but it *seems* like you are saying that you interrupted the release-upgrade while it was unpacking and installing packages. If true, that was the worst possible to to interrupt the release-upgrade process. You should be able to recover and backup your data by using a plain old LiveUSB. Then use the same LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to test 22.04 compatibility with your hardware, and if compatible then clean-install Ubuntu.

Comment: I see. I made a bootable usb that has ubuntu 22.04. Before I install the new system, do I need to remove the old 20.04?

Comment: No. Overwrite the old Ubuntu install. Just preserve the data that is valuable to you so it does not get overwritten.